# Xcode view doesn't handle click events after changing orientation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, storyboard, uiinterfaceorientation

I found the question for Android, but could not find it for Xcode so I created a new question.

I have a VC which has three subviews. in landscape mode -> image view (left), image-details view (center) and related items tableview on the right. In portrait mode the image view remains in the top left corner and image details on the top right, but the related tableview goes below image view. I am handling rotation by following code.

```
 - (void) updateLayoutForNewOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {
  CGRect detailsFrame = self.detailsView.frame;
  CGRect relatedFrame = self.relatedView.frame;
  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
    detailsFrame.origin.x = 300.0f;
    detailsFrame.origin.y = 69.0f;
    relatedFrame.origin.x = 709.0f;
    relatedFrame.origin.y = 20.0f;
} else {
    detailsFrame.origin.x = 330.0f;
    detailsFrame.origin.y = 50.0f;
    relatedFrame.origin.x = 10.0f;
    relatedFrame.origin.y = 400.0f;
}
self.detailsView.frame = detailsFrame;
self.relatedView.frame = relatedFrame;
 }
```

Now my issue is that I can click a table cell or image view in landscape mode, but cannot click the tableview cell in portrait mode. I have spent enough time figuring out what could be wrong, but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orientation is also handled in xib instead of the code. So please set the proper autoresizing masks in interface builder. Please see the diagram for better understanding.

[image: autoresizing masks]
If you have doubt then please ask me.

Comment: Thanks Girish. I am able to display views properly after rotation but i am not able to click on the image view (it has a UIButton on it which opens a preview page)

Comment: give different background color to each view & check is it works correct for both orientations which gives more clarifications to us. Try it & give me your feedback.

Comment: You are absolutely right. after changing bgcolor, I can see views have moved but contents on it is in correct place. What is the best way to bind views with subviews so both rotates together?

Comment: Got the solution. I set similar autosizing mask of view and subviews and its working fine now. thanks again. :)